# UI is responding only after Hot reload or restart in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I like to hide the `floatingActionButton` on scroll down and to show it when scrolling up. But it only works after hot restart or reload.

> transaction.dart

```
class Transaction extends StatefulWidget {
  const Transaction({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Transaction> createState() => _TransactionState();
}

bool isFab = false;

class _TransactionState extends State<Transaction> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: NestedScrollView(
                floatHeaderSlivers: true,
                headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
                      SliverAppBar(
                        pinned: true,
                        floating: true,
                        snap: true,
                        centerTitle: true,
                        title: Text(
                          "Money Manager",
                          style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.5),
                          strutStyle: StrutStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                        ),
                        bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            child: Text(
                              "Income",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 18, letterSpacing: 1.5),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            child: Text(
                              "Expense",
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 18, letterSpacing: 1.5),
                            ),
                          )
                        ]),
                      )
                    ],
                body: TabBarView(children: [Income(), Expense()]))),
        floatingActionButton: isFab ? Fab() : null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> expense.dart

```
class Expense extends StatefulWidget {
  const Expense({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Expense> createState() => _ExpenseState();
}

class _ExpenseState extends State<Expense> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.forward) {
          setState(() => isFab = true);
        } else if (notification.direction == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
          setState(() => isFab = false);
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: ListView.separated(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(),
              trailing: Text("- ₹2000"),
              title: Text("category"),
              subtitle: Text(formatter),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Divider();
          },
          itemCount: 30),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `isFab` is declared `false` as a global variable, so it won't be changed by a `setState` call. I don't exactly know why it starts to work after a hot reload or restart though.

To make it work you have to make it part of `_TransactionState`, and you also have to make it accessible from `ExpenseState` since you put the `NotificationListener` there.

But probably the simplest solution is to move the `NotificationListener` in `Transaction` as the body of the `Scaffold`, then declare the `isFab` variable as part of the `_TransactionState`.
You can see it [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=00451bf2a112add1fff24e02839df80e): I had to change something (like using the default FAB) to make the dartpad run, but now the FAB appears only when on top.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you help to make it part of _TransactionState, and to access it from ExpenseState

Comment: @Sh'Jil to achieve that, first I'd define a `GlobalKey` global variable , then pass it as `key` argument in the `Transaction` constructor. After that, you should be able to access the `_TransactionState` methods and variables by using `key.currentState` from the same dart file. If `ExpenseState` is in another file, you must make `_TransactionState` public.